# Beta site First Post and Late Answer review

Tags: support, review

Does site which are currently in beta have a First Post and Late Answer review?

If so then I'm a little curious as to why are low-quality posts and/or not-an-answers, like [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/10210/3487), allowed to creep in?

Answer (score 1):

Both the First Post and the Late Answer review queues are available for [any user with at least 350 rep](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues).  Whether or not anyone chooses to actually use them is a whole other story.